# How to say this specific number in chinese?

Tags: number

How can I tell this number in chinese,
“three million five hundred sixty-seven thousand”?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

3,567,000 separated every 3 digits in English

356,7000 separated every 4 digits Chinese

三百五十六万七千

Answer (score 2):

3567,000 = 三百五十六万七千

The way the Chinese count is:

一位数 (one digit number): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9  (一， 二， 三，四，五，六，七，八，九)

二位数 (two digits number): 10 --> 99 (十 --> 九十九)

三位数 (three digits number): 100 --> 999 (一百 --> 九百九十九)

四位数 (four digits number): 1,000 --> 9,999 (一千 --> 九千九百九十九)

五位数 (five digits number): 10,000 --> 99,999 (一万 --> 九万九千九百九十九)

六位数 (six digits number): 100,000 --> 999,999 (十万 --> 九十九万九千九百九十九)

七位数 (seven digits number): 1,000,000 --> 9,999,999 (一百万 --> 九百九十九万九千九百九十九)

八位数 (eight digits number): 10,000,000 --> 99,999,999 (一千万 --> 九千九百九十九万九千九百九十九)

九位数 (nine digits number): 100,000,000 --> 999,999,999 (一億 --> 九億九千九百九十九万九千九百九十九)

十位数 (ten digits number): 1,000,000,000 --> 9,999,999,999 (十億 --> 九十九億九千九百九十九万九千九百九十九)

Following 十億 will be 一百億，一千億， 一万億(一兆)

More example:

> 171,691,211 = 一億七千(一百)六十九万(一千)二百(一十)一

> 170,690,201 = 一億七千(零)六十九万(零)二百(零)一

*use 零 when you have to skip a digit level*

*Suggestion: in writing, it is completely acceptable to use Arabic numerals instead.*